# Store a data stream on hard disk in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, writefile, overlapped-io

In our application, we need to store a data stream from a camera to the hard disk, and because all the CPU cores are already occupied by calculus, we are trying to save every frame in a separate `.jpeg` file created with nvjpeg. What we see is that after a while, the hard drive goes to 100% usage, and if we stop the application it remains in writing mode for a while.

I did some checks and see that the maximum speed of this HDD is 100Mb/sec. For our `.jpeg`s, we need 60Mb/sec, so I change the code to do it with overlapped and no-buffering:

```cpp
HANDLE hfile = CreateFileW(fileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO eofi;
eofi.EndOfFile.QuadPart = dim;
SetFileInformationByHandle(hfile, FileEndOfFileInfo, &eofi, sizeof(FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO));
DWORD d = (DWORD)dim;
DWORD unA = d & 511;
if (unA) d += 512 - unA;
::WriteFile(hfile, buff, d, NULL, &overlapped);
DWORD n = 0;
while(n<d) GetOverlappedResult(hfile, &overlapped, &n, TRUE);
CloseHandle(hfile);
```

But the problem still happens; there is some peaks of 1Mb/sec and after a while the hard drive is 100%.

What is the cause of those peaks? How can I obtain maximum performance?

Comment: Probably, you're saturating the drive.  With quoted speeds, ymmv as they say.  I'd get myself an SSD, nvme ones are particularly fast.

Comment: SSD has low endurance, after 100,000 write  cycles it become unreliable

Comment: Some things you can look into : Memory mapped files, not allowing your calculus to eat up all the cores (so do actual resource managment, at least keep one core free for management), using boost::asio with buffer sizes matching DMA size of your drive (using DMA uses a lot less of your CPU). In the end this is an optimization issue and that often means a bit more low level access and control

Comment: _if we stop the application it remains in writing mode for a while_ That's the write-behind cache.  So yes, the drive can't keep up.  Maybe write your jpegs across more than one drive.

Comment: _SSD has low endurance_ True, not sure how fast they degrade,

Comment: You could try a RAID-0 array (with a hardware controller), striping the data across multiple hard disks should be much quicker.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes from experience that (dedicated hardware) would definitely work specifically combined with boost::asio and DMA sized buffers to reduce CPU load.